# Why is the integral of $\cos(x) - \sin(x)$ from $0$ to $π/4$ equal to $\sqrt2 - 1$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Why is $$\int_ {0}^{π/4}  {\cos(x)} - {\sin(x)} \ \mathrm{d}x=\sqrt2 -1$$

This answer popped up on a problem I was doing and it piqued my interest. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the (anti)derivatives of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$? Do you know how to do definite integration?

Comment: It piqued your interest, or it was assigned as homework?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\cos x - \sin x = \sqrt2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right).$$

Comment: Very nice hint.

Comment: Agreed, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos x - \sin x\ dx\\
=[\sin x + \cos x]_0^{\pi/4}\\
=\sin \frac{\pi}{4}+\cos\frac{\pi}4-\sin0-\cos0\\
=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-1\\
=\sqrt2-1$$